# For loop loops before completing task of downloading image, resulting in unordered images

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an unspecified number of images and display them in the order they were taken however the method I'm using to loop through and download the images results in a random image order displayed even though it should be in order.

I did a simple test to see if the loop was initiating the next loop before completing the tasks and it seems like that is the case.

I've tried using the .addView method with index specification but that gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0

```
for (int i = 1; i <= photoTakenAmount; i++) {
            String photoName = "Photo_" + String.valueOf((i)) + ".jpg";
            photoRef = firebaseStorage.getReference("users/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/Images/" + photoName);

            photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    View photo_imageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo_imageview, mViewPhotoLayout, false);
                    mViewPhotoLayout.addView(photo_imageView);
                    ImageView imageView = photo_imageView.findViewById(R.id.photo_imageview);
                    Glide.with(mViewPhotoLayout).load(uri).into(imageView);
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I get the images to load in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using loops you can donwload the  next image in `onSuccess` and make condition to stop the recursion.
this way ensures that each image will be loaded and showed in order

```
donwloadImage(0);

private downloadImage(int index){
        String photoName = "Photo_" + String.valueOf((index)) + ".jpg";
        photoRef = firebaseStorage.getReference("users/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/Images/" + photoName);

        photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                View photo_imageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo_imageview, mViewPhotoLayout, false);
                mViewPhotoLayout.addView(photo_imageView);
                ImageView imageView = photo_imageView.findViewById(R.id.photo_imageview);
                Glide.with(mViewPhotoLayout).load(uri).into(imageView);
             index++;
            if(index>photoTakenAmount)return;
            else downloadImage(index);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Replaced index with a variable to avoid the "index is accessed within a inner class and must be declared as final" and changed the parameter name to something else and it works :)